# regular expression: what's wrong with my expression?

Tags: regex

I have a difficulty building a regex.
Suppose there is a html clip as below.
I want to use Javascript to cut the `<tbody>` part with the link of "apple"(which `<a>` is inside of the `<td class="by">`)
I construct the following expression :

```
/<tbody.*?text[\s\S]*?<td class="by"[\s\S]*?<a.*?>apple<\/a>[\s\S]*?<\/tbody>/g
```

But the result is different from what I wanted. Each match contains more than one block of `<tbody>`. How it should be? Regards!!!!
 (I tested with https://regex101.com/ and get the unexpected selection. Please forgive me I can't figure out the problem :( )

```
   <tbody id="text_0">
        <td class="by">
                ...lots of other tags
            <a href="xxx">cat</a>
               ...lots of other tags
        </td>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="text_1">
               ...lots of other tags
        <td class="by">
            <a href="xxx">apple</a>
        </td>
               ...lots of other tags
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="text_2">
               ...lots of other tags
        <td class="by">
            <a href="xxx">cat</a>
        </td>
               ...lots of other tags
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="text_3">
               ...lots of other tags
        <td class="by">
               ...lots of other tags
            <a href="xxx">tiger</a>
        </td>
               ...lots of other tags
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="text_4">
        <td class="by">
            <a href="xxx">banana</a>
        </td>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="text_5">
        <td class="by">
            <a href="xxx">peach</a>
        </td>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="text_6">
        <td class="by">
            <a href="xxx">apple</a>
        </td>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="text_7">
        <td class="by">
            <a href="xxx">banana</a>
        </td>
    </tbody>
```

And this is what i expect to get

```
<tbody id="text_1">
    <td class="by">
        <a href="xxx">apple</a>
    </td>
</tbody>
<tbody id="text_6">
    <td class="by">
        <a href="xxx">apple</a>
    </td>
</tbody>
```

Comment: try putting it on regex101.com to see what is going wrong. for starters, the `text[\s\S]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh, sorry , the condition also select the <tbody> with id begins with "text". there are lots of other <tbody> with other serial id, but i didn't put it in the question

Comment: Before i post the question, I have tested with https://regex101.com/ and get the unexpected selection. I have no idea how to figure it out

Comment: include the link to regex101.com in your question

Comment: See this question on SO for more information about *why* regex won't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 0):

Start with this working regexp and go from there:

```
/<a href="(.*?)">apple<\/a>/g
```

If that is too broad and you want to make it more specific, add the next surrounding tag:

```
/<td.*?>\s*<a href="(.*?)">apple<\/a>/g
```

Then continue:

```
/<tbody.*?>\s*<td.*?>\s*<a href="(.*?)">apple<\/a>/g
```

Also, consider an alternate solution such as XPATH. Regular expressions can't really parse all variations of HTML.

Comment: Yes, but i want to get the block from <tbody> .... </tbody> as the return of string.match(reg)

Comment: well then add it to the regular expression.. as in putting `<tbody.*?>\s*<td.*?>\s*` in front of the starting regular expression I gave you. The point is you have to build them and start with something that works

Comment: This is a simpfied html clip. The target i am working on have lots of other tag between <tbody>, and i would like to select the whole part of the <tbody>, with the <a>apple</a> inside

Comment: I think i must put something like id="text.*? behind <tbody and as there are "lots of other tag"  inside of <tbody>(before and after <a>) i need the [\s\S]*? to include the line change

Comment: As I mentioned, regular expressions are not ideal for this.

Comment: Should i use DOM for such html parse/analyse, Or could there be some better(faster) way? For it is related with the UI and with DOM it took me almost 2 second for a parsing, which make my boss a green face.

Comment: The latest answer works very well in this case. I have to make a research for this knowledge and the XPATH you mentioned about. Thank everyone helped me! /<tbody.*?>\s*<td.*?>\s*<a href="(.*?)">apple<\/a>[\s\S]*?<\/tbody>/g

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the regex part of the question, but shouldn't the `td` elements be embedded in `tr` elements? `tr` stands for  "table row", while `tbody`  stands for "table body". `tbody` usually groups the table rows. It is not prohibited to have more than one `tbody` in the same table, but it is usually not necessary. (`tbody` is actually optional; you can have `tr` directly inside the `table` element.)

Comment: The real html i am working on have the right structure of html. But it is very huge and i make the question simple. The difficult for me is i cant get the right selection by testing in https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

First, Regex is not a good solution for parsing anything like HTML or XML.

I can fix your pattern to work with this specific example but I can't guarantee that it will work in all cases. Regex just is not the right tool for the job.

But anyway, replace the first 2 instances of `[\s\S]` in your pattern with `[^<]`.

`<tbody.*?text[^<]*?<td class="by"[^<]*?<a.*?>apple<\/a>[\s\S]*?</tbody>`

Comment: I tried with DOM and it works well, with the only problem...very slow and give my boss a bad feeling and make me feel same....When i tried with Regex and it is much much faster, without right response  8...(. The real html i works on could be few hundred kb.

Comment: Thanks, it works like magic. I will try to learn from your answer and make it work with my real "html clip". Thank you very much again!! You saved my day!

Comment: Sorry it is not working if there are other uncertain tags inside of <tbody>, for example if the second part is like this will not be selected<tbody id="text_1">
 <sas></saa>
 <td class="by">
  <a href="xxx">apple</a>
 </td>
</tbody>

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Now you see why everyone is saying not use Regex. *Regular* expressions only work for *regular* languages and HTML is not a regular language. This is like trying to drive a nail into a board using a screwdriver instead of hammer. You're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Agree. finally i used XPath slove the problem. To the speed it is a little slower as the Regex but much faster than DOM/JQuerySelector